# bug, how to debug?

Tags: debugging, mono, opencl

My application suddenly breaks without even showing a managed stacktrace. It shows the following message in the console:

```
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xac5ac2c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mono(6417,0xb0307000) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Native stacktrace:

    0   mono                                0x000b6ea9 mono + 745129
    1   mono                                0x00006e23 mono + 24099
    2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9487c59b _sigtramp + 43
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    4   libclh.dylib                        0x9776bbbb libclh.dylib + 191419
    5   libclh.dylib                        0x97773564 libclh.dylib + 222564
    6   libclh.dylib                        0x977b0456 clhFenceCreate + 38
    7   GeForceGLDriver                     0x8f0dca23 glrCompExecuteKernel + 5034
    8   OpenCL                              0x9a691ff1 processExec + 506
    9   OpenCL                              0x9a696ec6 processWork + 214
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x9282f80b _dispatch_queue_drain + 224
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x9282f6b0 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 47
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x9282eeb8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 187
    13  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x94826b24 _pthread_wqthread + 346
    14  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x948286fe start_wqthread + 30

Debug info from gdb:

/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.DNbmkH:1: Error in sourced command file:
unable to debug self

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

It seems that the problem is inside OpenCL driver. How can I trace and solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a problem with memory leak in interop, and it caused to suckout all available memory, when went beyond 2gb it crashed... So thanks everybody, mine fault...

Answer (score 0):

It more looks like it's happeining in OpenCL (note the 'C', this is not OpenGL, but has a relationship to it). What's probably going on is, that your program tries to map some GPU memory into its address space, but this fails, because there's no piece of address space left, that's large enough and has the proper alignment. And somewhere in the low loevel code the pointer returned by mmap is not checked, which causes the segfault.

This clearly is a bug of either Mono or your OpenCL/OpenGL driver or in the bindings for it. Send the above trace to either of the developers, filing a bug issue.

Comment: It is interesting because the program works for about 10 minutes and then crashes. All memory allocations are done during it's initialization, and there are no memory allocations during processing, no GPU memory is also allocated during computation, really strange...

Comment: @Lu4: What makes you think there are no memory allocations? Mono/.net is a garbage collected system. Memory is allocated and discarded behind the scenes all the time. As long as this happens within Mono the memory management can cope with the occuring address space fragmentation (the garbage collector rearranges the memory layout every now and then). However introduce some system that expects a clean address space, OpenGL, OpenCL, etc. and all kinds of strange interactions are about to happen.

Comment: I've ran the program on windows the same problem, but it gave me stack trace, the problem with clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects. It is also strange because I'm calling appropriate clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects later, I'm starting new thread

Comment: @Lu4: Ahh, starting a new thread may be the culprit as well: A OpenGL context must be active in only one thread at a time and all OpenGL commands must be called from this very thread. Trying to access OpenGL from other threads will cause serious problems.

Answer (score 0):

It s a matter of a massive memory allocation in the CALayer context , you need to free the layer every time you change the view. It happened to me and that's how I solved it, you need to release the memory each time you change a page drawing certain context.